# How to render increasement value in vuejs without using v-loop?

Tags: vue.js

Not using v-for, how can I manual create an increase variable in vuejs?

```
<comp :prop-data="page++">Some logic 1</comp>
<comp v-if="dataPage2Exist" :prop-data="page++">Difference logic of Page 2</comp>
<comp :prop-data="page++">Differnce logic of page 3</comp>
```

I try using data return but there is an error says that 'Infinitive loop'

Comment: vue js provide an index in v-for

Comment: My case is not using v-for

Comment: So ? Start using it as it is only way how to do that in Vue. Period.

Comment: @MichalLevý I just need to render manual because some if-else logic behind

Comment: This seems as [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Update your question with what you want to achieve (X) instead of asking about attempted solution (Y)

Comment: Is the number of pages fixed? Also what is the point of passing `prop-data` prop into `<div>` ? What does it do ?

Comment: Sorry @MichalLevý my mistake, i changed to component element. Number of page is increase +1 (if page 2 does not have data skip page 2 and page 3 become page 2)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is making a loop from 1 to n.

The infinite loop happens because Vue is updating the page because the variable changes. The variable changes because the page renders.

You have to create a loop to make it stop.

```
<!-- loop 10 times -->
<div>
  <span v-for="n in 10">{{ n }}</span>
</div>
```

Instead of `10` you can also have a variable in data which is the number of iterations.

See [Vue documentation: v-for with a range](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range)

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Peter but my case cannot using v-for.

Comment: v-for is only using for data that the same type and structure, but in my case, data is come from many source and its free style

Answer (score 0):

I found that one solution here. If you have the same problem as me.

```
data() {
    return {
      pages: [0, 1, 2, 3],
    }
  },
mounted() {
    if (!this.dataPage2Exist()) {
      this.pages = [0, 1, 2, 2]
    }
  }
```

and then in component

```
<comp :prop-data="pages[1]">Some logic 1</comp>
<comp v-if="dataPage2Exist" :prop-data="pages[2]">Difference logic of Page 2</comp>
<comp :prop-data="pages[3]">Differnce logic of page 3</comp>
```